# Como crear rutina que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo con Node Js para hacer un registro en una base datos

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

La idea es que cada inicio de mes se haga un registro en una tabla, por ejemplo que cuando sea 1 de diciembre se haga un nuevo registro automáticamente

Comment: Que haz intentado? Adjunta tu código.

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas dos cosas, Nodejs y el Shell. Si usas linux puedes ejecutar un cronjob y mandar a llamar a un archivo javascript que contenga tu código. O puedes hacer algo más genial y usar node-cron.

Es realmente muy sencillo de usar:

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task every minute');
});
```

Las asteriscos son parametros de tiempo. En la página lo explican mejor de lo que podría hacerlo yo. ¡Y recuerda que lo que quieres ejecutar cada cierto tiempo va dentro del callback!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero en el sitio tratamos de responder preguntas donde el OP deje claro lo que haya intentado. Si bien tu respuesta puede ser válida, seguramente no será la única forma de resolver el problema. La pregunta del OP es muy amplia y basada en opiniones. Y sin saber exactamente lo que ha intentado (si acaso ha intentado algo), no podemos responderle de forma apropiada. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Use este código, imprime un mensaje cada 2 min. Lo que requiero hacer es, programarlo para que cada inicio de mes haga un registro en una tabla

const Scheduled = require("scheduled")

```
const myJob = new Scheduled({
    id: "minuteTaskEven",
    pattern: "*/2", 
    task: function(){
        console.log("Hola mundo!");
    }
}).start()
```

Comment: Hola, esto no provee una respuesta, es una edición de tu pregunta. Este espacio sólo es para respuestas. Por favor edita tu pregunta agregando esto. Para ello haz clic en [edit]. Luego elimina esta respuesta, ya que no lo es. Saludos